# Apache Drill S3 : No default schema selected

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to work with Apache Drill. I am new to this whole environment, just trying to understand how Apache Drill works.

I am trying to query my json data stored on s3 using Apache Drill.
My bucket is created in **US East (N. Virginia)**.
I have created a new Storage Plugin for S3 using [this](https://drill.apache.org/docs/s3-storage-plugin/) link.

Here is the configuration for my new S3 Storage Plugin :

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "s3a://testing-drill/",
  "config": {
    "fs.s3a.access.key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "fs.s3a.secret.key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
      ],
      "delimiter": "|"
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "tsv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tsv"
      ],
      "delimiter": "\t"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    },
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    },
    "avro": {
      "type": "avro"
    },
    "sequencefile": {
      "type": "sequencefile",
      "extensions": [
        "seq"
      ]
    },
    "csvh": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csvh"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
    }
  }
}
```

I have also configured my `core-site-example.xml` as follows:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

But when I try to use/set the workspace using the following command :

```
USE shiv.`root`;
```

It gives me following error :

```
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Schema [shiv.root] is not valid with respect to either root schema or current default schema.

Current default schema:  No default schema selected

[Error Id: 6d9515c0-b90f-48aa-9dc5-0c660f1c06ca on ip-10-0-3-241.ec2.internal:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

If try to execute `show schemas;`, then I get the following error :

```
show schemas;
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: EEB438A6A0A5E667, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 85883537-9b4f-4057-9c90-cdaedec116a8 on ip-10-0-3-241.ec2.internal:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

I am not able to understand the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Seems to me that the configuration is set wrong since it says `Bad Request`. Maybe step through the setup again?

Comment: Can you add  "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" in config section of your storage plugin definition? Also, you may rename core-site-example.xml to core-site .xml, restart drill-bit and try.

Comment: The same configuration worked when I launched the instance in public subnet and started the service. I was able to work with Drill. I don't know what was the issue but it is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using Apache Drill with GCS(Google Cloud Storage)

I was getting the following error when running `USE gcs.data` query.

```
VALIDATION ERROR: Schema [gcs.data] is not valid with respect to either root schema or current default schema.

Current default schema:  No default schema selected
```

I ran `SHOW SCHEMAS` and there was no `gcs.data` schema.

I went ahead and created `data` folder in my GCS bucket and `gcs.data` showed up in `SHOW SCHEMAS` and `USE gcs.data` query worked.

From my limited experience with apache drill what I understood is that,
In file storage, if you have a workspace that uses a folder that does not exist then drill will throw this error.

GCS and S3 both are file type storage so maybe you are having this issue.

---

Here is my GCS storage config

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "gs://my-gcs-bkt",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "data": {
      "location": "/data",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    },
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    },
    "tsv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tsv"
      ],
      "delimiter": "\t"
    },
    "csvh": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csvh"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
      ],
      "delimiter": "|"
    }
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```